# Are there any other considerations I need to think about for Login screen in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, security, hash

I have created a login page with the standard Username and Password textboxes (radTextbox) and a Login button. In the markup I have limited the Username textbox to MaxLength = "50". For the Password textbox I set its MaxLength at runtime by reading from a Password requirements table and setting in the Page_load event.

In the database I have a User table that contains the Username in plain text but the Password column is using a Hash that is 512 bytes with an embedded Salt value that is 100 bytes. Additionally before the hash I am doing "Key Stretching" by concatenating the password with the primary key of the user record which is a Guid. I am using RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes for the Salt and then calling Rfc2898DeriveBytes with the stretched password, salt and iteration count of 10000. Then some extra constants are added on to the hash value then stored to the User table. At login I take the typed in password and send it through the same process and use Linq to pull the user record based off the username
and compare byte by byte of the two hashes to know if the password is correct.

The data I am protecting is not that sensitive but I am trying to do my due diligence for security.
So as far as the Login screen is concerned, should I be thinking about any other things or concerns? Would it be unreasonable to add some type of Captcha to a login screen?

Comment: First think about whether you want to create YAID (yet another identity database). Not sure of the context here but people are used to single sign on - they don't want to have to create and remember yet another password. If this is just a little experiment, fine, but if this is something to be deployed to public users, consider OAuth2. If it is intended to be deployed to corporate users, consider using whatever your corporate identity provider is.

Comment: This will be a public user setting and the same authentication will be used for a related API access. I will have to think about the OAuth2 and do some research. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decided to use PBKDF2 (which is fine) you should consider:

- Hashing algorithm
- Salt size
- Number of iterations
- PBKDF2 output size

Hashing algorithm should be

- Pre-image resistance
- Second pre-image resistance
- Collision-resistance

SHA2 family would address those requirements.
The real-world security aim is **128 bits of security**.
Due to birthday attack, min hash size should be of 256 bits.
So you could use **SHA-256** or **SHA-512**.

An attacker will probably use GPUs for speeding up brute force attack.
GPUs use 32-bit arithmetic (the same as SHA-256).
So you should use **SHA-512** which uses 64-bit arithmetic.

SHA-512 output size is...512 bits (64 bytes). This should be length of password hash column.

Sticking to the rule of 128 bits of security, I would limit **salt size to 128 bits**.
Salt is protecting against precomputation attacks, so 128 is just fine.

Number of iterations is not defined. Hardware is getting better and better, so it changes all the time. It affects usability, as authentication takes also more time. I would suggest to increase it to 100.000.

Additionally, I would recommend to use Pepper - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography).